# Ruby on Rails gems for social media profiles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am new to ruby on rails and transferred from php into ruby on rails and I find it really great specially the fast development of it.

My questions is that , Is there any gems out there that I can use for my personal project that i am currently working on that would enable CRUD of users into my project with profiles , friends etc. or anything like a social media gems or do i have to make it manually?

Anything on this will help loads and thanks!

Comment: Team treehouse has a good tutorial on how to implement a FB like feature in your rails app: https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/treebook-ruby-on-rails-tutorial

Comment: Thank you for the information! I am currently looking at it now

Answer (score 1):

You have lot more social media gems to work with rails.If you need authentication for your app you can use **devise** https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

or you can use different gems for different social media sites

for example **twitter** you can use **'gem twitter'** https://github.com/sferik/twitter

for **facebook: koala gem** check this link https://github.com/arsduo/koala

Hope this helps you some extent

Comment: Thanks for the info I already checked the Devise but havent checked these other gems twitter and koala gems thanks again for the info and i am now looking at this!